# Should 'Q:' be removed from question titles

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, title

The leading `Q:` seems redundant to me.  Is there a reason I should not remove it from every question title I come across?

Comment: Is this just in search results?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583602/q-sql-filtering-with-a-derived-table) is just one example where it is appearing because the asker typed it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, you should remove them. That is very silly and I don't know why anyone would put that in a question title. But when you do, please look for other things to improve as well!

Comment: In order to increase load on reviewers with minor edits such as removing `Q:` I will only remove `Q:` from titles if I have other significant edits to make.

Comment: That's pretty much how to do it, yep! Thank you!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't remove the `Q:` from this question title ;)

Comment: @doubleDown your comment makes this discussion truly "meta"

Comment: No really: **"Q: Should 'Q:' be removed from question titles?"**.

Comment: A: The answer is 'yes'

Comment: Incidentally, there are [only six questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3aq%3a) that have `Q:` in their title, which also makes search results [quite amusing](http://i.imgur.com/4zhX0zC.png)

Answer (score 9):

Unless `Q:` is, in some way, related to the question itself, it should be removed from question titles, after all, questions are the only thing that have titles!

If you don't have the reputation to edit questions without sending them through review make sure you check the body and tags of the question for other things that need fixing. The chances are, if the title contains `Q:`, the body will have other things that need editing as well.

Comment: I suggest you add the proviso that it is not part of the question, as in relevant to the coding problem

Comment: @Yve Okay, done.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the reputation to directly edit them, then yes, absolutely. As the only edit in the suggested edit queue, I'd vote to reject as Too Minor every time; removing 2 characters from the title isn't worth reviewers' time in my opinion.