# Is there any way to see what answers were deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I can look at my profile and get a list of "questions answered" and "comments made".

Q: Is there a similar way to get a list of "posts deleted"?

Q: What is the protocol for requesting "un-delete"?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted?rq=1.

Comment: Would these be posts that you have deleted yourself?

Comment: @Zizouz212 - Ideally, there should be a list of *all* "deleted posts", including those I deleted myself.  Unfortunately, at the moment I can't find *any* list of deleted posts.  The two meta.stackexchange.com links posted above don't seem to be any help: there's an "experimental feature" that doesn't appear to exist anymore, and a "dead link" that goes to "site not found".  But no way to find a list of "deleted" posts.

Comment: Why do you need Q: in the title? I see you rolled back the change made by @rene

Comment: @paulsm4 I've posted an answer to see self-deleted posts. Check it out

Comment: You *really* shouldn't put Q: in the title. We already know that this is a question. There's no need to emphasize that.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm trying to find out if there's any way I can find out if somebody arbitrarily deletes my post.  If somebody arbitrarily changes my title, I at least get notified.  I understand the "convention" is "no Q".  I don't understand why somebody would insist on changing it if I feel otherwise.

Comment: In any case, the answer to my question appears to be "No, there is no notification if a post is deleted.  And no, there is no way to review which (if any) posts have been deleted".  Correct?

Comment: I don't think you get notified for deleted posts, but I'm not completely sure. People got a little frustrated with the Q because you rollbacked their edits, including that of a moderator. If you want some notification, look for rep changes, deleting reverse downvotes, and deletion only normally happens to low quality posts - which are generally downvoted.

Comment: Yes: just get elected as a moderator, and you can view deleted posts on profiles.

Comment: With all due respect I have again removed the Q: from the title because I edit in the spirit of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188317/should-q-be-removed-from-question-titles/188321#188321). Please don't roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see any posts that you have cast a vote on, you'll need to follow these steps:

1. Go to your profile page, namely go to the activity tab (it should go there automatically)
2. Click the "votes" tab, beside the other tabs (they include questions, answers, summary...)
3. Clicking the "votes" tab, you should see a list of all votes that you have ever cast. To filter out deletion votes (or posts you have deleted), you'll need to click the "deletion" tab, right under the votes tab.
4. Voila! You should be able to see any self-deleted posts.

---

If you would like to undelete a post that you have created, and deleted *yourself*, you simply need to go to that post, and click the neat little undelete button, just beside the edit and share buttons.

If someone else has deleted the question, for example a moderator, you'll need to flag the post for undeletion, and be sure to include what efforts you have made since the post was deleted, and why you think it should be undeleted. Remember, that this is the moderator's decision.

To see full details: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?lq=1)

Comment: Hey, Zizousz212 - I'd really like to thank you for your help.
The answer to my original question ("all posts") is "No - I can't see them, I won't get notified, there's no existing mechanism for me to track deletions in general".  As far as my *own* deletions: there *is* a mechanism, and you described it perfectly.  Thank you.  Let me definitely "accept" your reply.

Comment: Do you need to have access to moderator tools to see that? I checked in my SO profile, and it says I have only casted one delete vote. I'm pretty sure I've never deleted that answer before, and I am certain I have deleted more than one answer.

Comment: You shouldn't need mod tools for that: they are your own posts, but in a deleted state. They should all be there, as even with mod tools, you can't see others votes (which include deletion). You may not see them if they were deleted by a mod, or if there were deleted more than 60 days ago, but I'm not entirely sure.